# error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFound

Tags: java, permissions, intellij-idea, rmi, executable-jar

I've been working on a little program using RMI and I want to try testing my client side as a jar (perhaps put it on a different computer using my own localhost as the ip to connect to) but everytime I compile it in Intellij with VM Options:

```
-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=src/test.policy
```

and this is my test.policy:

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1024-65535",
"connect,accept,resolve";
};
```

When I compile it in Intellij, after I put in the host(localhost) it gives me the message in the title

```
error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFound: ServerImplements_Stub
```

I am asking how do I get this to work in a jar or even compiling in Intellij to work?

Here is the code to my entire project

Client.java

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Client extends JFrame {
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JButton b = new JButton("Send message");
    RemoteInterface s;
    String name;
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();


    public Client() {
        super("Chat client v1.0 by Jurko Guba");
        setSize(250, 250);
        setLocation(300, 300);
        getContentPane().add(p);
        p.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        try {
            textArea.setText(s.returnChat());
        } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}

    try {
        String ipp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter IP Address to Connect");
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter chat username ie. Jurko");
        String ip = "rmi://" + ipp + "/RMIAPPLICATION";
        s = (RemoteInterface)Naming.lookup(ip);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exp.getMessage());
    }

   b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           try {
               s.addChatMessage(name + ": " + textField.getText());
               textArea.setText(s.returnChat());
               textArea.repaint();
               System.out.println("Client message added: "+textField.getText() + " under the name of: "+name);

           } catch (Exception epx) {System.out.println(epx.getMessage());}
       }
   });
   }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:test.policy");
        System.out.println(java.security.Policy.getPolicy());
        Client c = new Client();
        c.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        c.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.rmi.Naming;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: jurkoguba
 * Date: 2013-09-10
 * Time: 9:14 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class Server {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        try {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
            System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file://test.policy");
            ServerImplements s = new ServerImplements();
            Naming.rebind("RMIAPPLICATION", s);
            System.out.println("Server has been started!");
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Server");
            f.setSize(250, 250);
            f.setLocation(100, 100);
            f.getContentPane().add(s.textArea);
            f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            f.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }



    }

}

RemoteInterface.java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.rmi.*;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: jurkoguba
 * Date: 2013-09-10
 * Time: 8:56 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public interface RemoteInterface extends Remote {

    public void addChatMessage(String message) throws Exception;
    public String returnChat() throws Exception;

}
```

ServerImplements.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: jurkoguba
 * Date: 2013-09-10
 * Time: 9:01 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class ServerImplements extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RemoteInterface {

    public ServerImplements() throws Exception {
        super();
    }

    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Brand new chat!");
        public void addChatMessage(String message) {

            textArea.append('\n'+message);
            System.out.println("Message appended: "+ message);
            textArea.repaint();

    }

    public String returnChat() throws Exception {
        return textArea.getText();
    }

}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you getting that (1) when exporting, (2) when binding, or (3) when looking up?

Comment: When I am in Intellij, if I build the program directly from there with the 'Client' being the main file, that is when I recieve this error. THe only time I can run my program properly is when I run the client in terminal using java Client or when I click on the Client.class in the finder. If I haven't made myself clear please tell me I would really like this to work because it will solve many problems for me in the future thanks a lot!

Comment: You haven't answered the question. I gave you three alternatives. Which is it? I suggest you include the stack trace in your question.

Comment: EJP, I am very sorrry but I do not understand by what you mean in those 3 options? if by exporting you mean Building artifacts and turning into a jar? When I turn it into a jar, it doesn't even start. I do not know what binding and when looking up means. I am so greatful that you are taking the time to help but could you please elaborate? Thank you very much

Comment: I changed the code where it said System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager()); to new RMISecurityManager and that works when I run it in intellij but when I export (turn to jar), I can't start it

Comment: Do you understand what is meant by 'include the stack trace'? If you don't, there isn't much point in posting here. None actually. You will get no help until you do so. NB `Exporting' a remote object means constructing it, or calling `exportObject()` if you do that. If you don't know what `bind()` means, you aren't doing RMI at all. Ditto `lookup().`